# Possible to use magic methods __get and __set for both array and nonarray class member variables?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, getter-setter, magic-methods

I currently have the following __get/__set methods in the PHP class example:

```
class example{

    /*Member variables*/
    protected $a; 
    protected $b = array(); 

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

}
```

However, in addition to setting standard protected variables, I would also like to be able to set protected arrays within the class. I've looked through some other questions and found general suggestions as to how to simple set variables using the __get/__set methods, but nothing that would allow one to use these magic methods to set BOTH arrays and nonarrays, i.e. in the following manner:

```
$fun = new $example(); 
$fun->a = 'yay'; 
$fun->b['coolio'] = 'yay2';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, define `__get()` like so:

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    return $this->$name;
}

// ...

$fun = new example();
$fun->a = 'yay';
$fun->b['coolio'] = 'yay2';
var_dump($fun);
```

Output:

```
object(example)#1 (2) {
  ["a":protected]=>
  string(3) "yay"
  ["b":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["coolio"]=>
    string(4) "yay2"
  }
}
```

Do take necessary care when you're dealing with references, it's easy to mess up and introduce hard to track bugs.

Comment: Impressive, if that's really possible x) But I have to say, how is this not documented? [**PHP magic methods**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: This is documented briefly but I wanted to delve a bit further. If get is being set by reference, will the set function remain identical to before? Additionally, given the risk of bugs with a get function that involves references, would you suggest that I simply create a different set of functions to deal with arrays?

Comment: `__set()` is only called when the property as a whole is being assigned a value, i.e. `$fun->b = something_else;`

Comment: Even after all these years, I just.cant.believe that returning by ref *does not actually enable modification of the protected variable through that ref if the ref is assigned to a variable* (you 'd need `$a = &$fun->foo` to enable that). Well played, PHP, well played. Am I missing something or is this a) completely unreasonable, b) par for the course, and c) reason enough to *always* make `__get` return by ref?

Comment: @Jon Apparently, according to [this 3v4l](http://3v4l.org/efd8b) it's supposed to work this way ... I'm a ... surprised a little myself :)

Comment: @Jack: Turns out it's a "simple" case of [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php): *Note: Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use & in both places - to indicate that you want to return by reference, not a copy, and to indicate that reference binding, rather than usual assignment, should be done for $myValue.* Of course the made-up explanation could be shortened to simply "because PHP", but there it is.

Comment: @Jon Well, the good news is that by the time you have to add the second `&` you probably know what you're doing :)